# Facebook, stop caching a page, how to?

Tags: php, facebook, caching

Lets say, I have an article which supposed to be shown next week, for an hour. When viewing this article, it defends itself:

```
if ($post->date < NEXT WEEK || $post->date > NEXT WEEK)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header('Location: http://example.com/404');
    exit();
}
```

this works very good but sadly a sitemap is working around here or whatever. Facebook still caches that 404 page. How to ask facebook not to cache that page?

Comment: _“How to ask facebook not to cache that page?”_ - not possible. At most you can trigger a re-scrape, so that Facebook will notice something changed _then_. But answering with an error status code won’t work either - that makes Facebook _not_ update their cache, but keep using the existing data. (And 301 moved permanently without a location is rather complete nonsense.)

Comment: _“I have an article which supposed to be shown next week, for an hour”_ - sound to me as if it would not make the most sense to share that on Facebook to begin with then.

Comment: but they say its being shared, maybe a sitemap.xml or something

Comment: I mean somehow google had cached it as 404 page already

Comment: You can’t compare that kind of caching to what Facebook does ... that isn’t actually “HTTP caching.” If you do not want this shared on Facebook at all (due to it’s time-limited validity), then perhaps you should rather block the Facebook scraper (or redirect it elsewhere) when it requests this particular resource, by checking for its User-Agent.

Comment: hmm, is there a way to tell who visited the page, a human or facebook?

Comment: ... _“by checking for its User-Agent”_ ...

Answer (score 0):

Add follow strings:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: " . date("r"));
```

Comment: I really hope that this is interpretered by facebook, not Google only

Comment: @JohnSmith pretty sure it won’t be.